# Cannot return `<AmplifyContext.Provider />` because property `client` is missing in `React.Element` [1] but exists in `Client`

Tags: flowtype

Cannot return `<AmplifyContext.Provider />` because property `client` is missing in `React.Element` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCh4EsC2AHaAnALgAmwJ5oCmuA3rgHLQAmpAvruJtCrgOSbECGAxtu1zJ0WPACUe-ADTlcvLt2zEAwtAB2SgB55GzVhwX92iXuoDOeAILpIScAVUbi23AF45CpY63YAPGoBXSEgAPgAKQOCASlxYxEISXGVbYg03cnhY3hSNAC4M2NjLAOwAC3yyeilMwssABQBJCqqa2IBzTG40UoBHSAB5Ek7sJHV8gDdoJBoalqzSpEgaLjUAfnzqOnh6RGcMHDlzKxs7AjqWceniTHSwimykVOwZXgWlldx6KPzkx7TXEIFXBcbABTBqXC+axoWz2bzObAAOnO0EudBu424kACxFcZAeT3oIXxb2WqXovmA0NhDnUPmRFyumBC23gQA) but exists in `Client`

How to fix the error?

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCh4EsC2AHaAnALgAmwJ5oCmuA3rgHLQAmpAvruJtCrgOSbECGAxtu1zJ0WPACUe-ADTlcvLt2zEAwtAB2SgB55GzVhwX92iXuoDOeAILpIScAVUbi23AF45CpY63YAPGoBXSEgAPgAKQOCASlxYxEISXGVbYg03cnhY3hSNAC4M2NjLAOwAC3yyeilMwssABQBJCqqa2IBzTG40UoBHSAB5Ek7sJHV8gDdoJBoalqzSpEgaLjUAfnzqOnh6RGcMHDlzKxs7AjqWceniTHSwimykVOwZXgWlldx6KPzkx7TXEIFXBcbABTBqXC+axoWz2bzObAAOnO0EudBu424kACxFcZAeT3oIXxb2WqXovmA0NhDnUPmRFyumBC23gQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction for the solution is to type return value with usage `React.Element` and `React.ComponentType`. I put together the start of the solution (open [in flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCh4EsC2AHaAnALgAgFS4CGAzrgEoCmRAxnuJtCrgOSbV0u7LpZ4DeuGuyLZKAYWgA7MQA88AX1wMmrEZ0Q1pJPAEF0kJOACekmZXm4AvEJFizc7AB4pAV0iQAfAAo3HgJS43PDYxmiUuOKGlDIAKmERNrj88EFBuq7YABYAXMkKADSpaboACgCSefyFxUEA5phEaFkAjpAA8uGN2EjSeQBu0EgAJvAKANyIoeG4sdYUHNgAdJK8UjHY8eFOKUH9RJCulHlEUsZFQTTRMnlRSBtbEQA+uH6QF0JZSJDD7FIA-HkqLRlgA5aDDShjTyTEIJSLXPA2YF0JYAUUglBQGycsRhiAsGBwQm0egMRmMpUY-RGlEw828giu9xkBU+31+MVwCiqly+Pz+gIWIKW4MhbOZGzyb25-luiOsnmSxXY2FcmCkuCc+jQhhMDgsyyp0BpkPp+0OlCs-ElMgUnht-M5UgUTmAOr1pmkjiWxtNdM8Y0QQA)), though I fell that better typing around `client` still needed there